# Plugin like CSS-X fire for other IDEs

Tags: css, firefox, plugins

I'm using the [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) IDE, and it has a wonderful plugin called [CSS-X fire](http://code.google.com/p/css-x-fire/) that integrates with firebug: whenever I make changes in the CSS via Firebug, and the PhpStorm project is open, the plugin makes PhpStorm aware of the cahnge, and enables me to apply it in the code.
My question is if there is a similar plugin for other IDEs (such as Visual Studio) or editors (such as Notepad++), since I'm not sure we're going to buy PhpStorm, and we also have projects not in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [cssUpdater](http://www.cssupdater.com/). It is a CSS-X-Fire spin-off that works directly on selected files rather than communicating with the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Using CssUpdater with Visual Studio 2012 worked great for me. You only need to install firefox addon [CssUpdater](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cssupdater/) and sync the files you are going to work on.